# Trying to put images inside a grid

Tags: html, css

I am creating a blog for a project and I am having an issue putting five images inside a grid and keeping them contained inside of it.  I am also trying to make it responsive, but not sure on how to do it. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
.container div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: aqua;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  /* background-color: wheat; */
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 80px;
  grid-template-areas: "t t t t t t t t t s s s" "c c c c c c c c c s s s" "f f f f f f f f f f f f";
}

.title {
  grid-area: t;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1vw);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  background-color: wheat;
  grid-template-areas: "p p p p p";
}

.pic {
  grid-area: p;
}

.content {
  grid-area: c;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.side {
  grid-area: s;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: f;
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title id="title">Otaku Life</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles-grids.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Economica&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<header class="header">
  <nav>
    <a href="/" class="logo">Otaku Life</a>
    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn">
    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Recommendations</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
<div class="image">
  <h1></h1>

</div>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">
      <div class="pic">
        <figure class="grid-images">
          <img src="https://ib3.hulu.com/user/v3/artwork/e95d9367-ee0f-425c-b8c7-472962669b58?base_image_bucket_name=image_manager&base_image=0858718f-8a0f-44e2-bfef-2976fa5353f6&size=400x600&format=jpeg" width="177" height="248">
        </figure>
        <figure class="grid-images">
          <img src="https://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/hotlink/thumbnails/max450x450/cms/news.3/156958/0220_78300_cr_tower-of-god-key-visual_crunchyroll-lockups2x3.png.jpg" width="177" height="248">
        </figure>
        <figure class="grid-images">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/b1/Black_Clover_vol_6.png/220px-Black_Clover_vol_6.png" width="177" height="248">
        </figure>
        <figure class="grid-images">
          <img src="https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/6/73245.jpg" width="177" height="248">
        </figure>
        <figure class="grid-images">
          <img src="https://ib4.hulu.com/user/v3/artwork/e567be4f-2fd8-4127-bc08-580baad908e3?base_image_bucket_name=image_manager&base_image=02294b7e-93de-4311-bbd5-c5cfda5baf7d&size=400x600&format=jpeg" width="177" height="248">
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="side">SIDE</div>
    <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid

Comment: I'd recommend to use bootstrap for this, it would make things way simpler: https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

Consider getting rid of the  elements and using css to set the background-url of the parent container. Then with css you can use...

```
.parentElement {
    background-url: url('path/to/image.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```